# Plotly shows blank white area with legend without my map

Tags: python, json, geojson, plotly-python, choropleth

I would like to create a choropleth map of Italy (regional level) with Plotly. I was following the tutorial from their site, however I am continuously getting just white area with legend (no map, no data).

I have the number of cases (of one event) for each Italian region and I would like to get the map where regions are colored according to the number of cases.

That's my data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Abruzzo', 313], ['Basilicata', 228], ['Calabria', 17], ['Campania', 101], ['Emilia-Romagna', 430],
        ['Friuli Venezia Giulia', 264],['Lazio', 451],['Liguria', 199],['Lombardia', 1765],['Marche', 17],
        ['Molise', 210], ['Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol', 86], ['Piemonte', 145], ['Puglia', 48],
        ['Sardegna', 257], ['Sicilia', 819], ['Toscana', 627],['Umbria', 389], ['Veneto', 436]]
 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['reg_name', 'cases'])
```

I have found geojson file containing map of Italy with regional borders in public access on [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_regions.geojson).

That's my code for choropleth map:

```
        it_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_regions.geojson'
        import urllib.request
        import json
        
        def read_geojson(url):
            with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
                jdata = json.loads(url.read().decode())
            return jdata 
        jdata = read_geojson(it_url)
        
        
    from plotly import graph_objects as go
    
    fig = go.Figure(
        go.Choroplethmapbox(
            geojson = jdata, #Assign geojson file
            featureidkey = "properties.reg_name", #Assign feature key
            locations = df["reg_name"],#Assign location data
            z = df["cases"], #Assign information data
            colorscale = 'viridis',
            showscale = True,
        )
    )
    fig.show()
```

That's the result of this code execution:

[image: Blank_Coropleth]

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer [here](https://medium.com/polimi-data-scientists/how-to-visualize-the-spread-of-covid-19-in-italy-6d9ddea18a02) and have got my choropleth map.

```
import plotly.express as px
import json
fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_regions.geojson', locations='reg_name', color='cases', color_continuous_scale='viridis', featureidkey='properties.reg_name', range_color=(0, max(df['cases'])))
fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()
```